# Algorithm to factor into a few factors as possible

Tags: algorithm

Is there a know algorithm to factor an integer into as few factors as possible (not necessarily prime) where every factor is less than some given constant N?

I don't care about numbers with a prime factor greater than N. Also, I'm not dealing with numbers greater than a few million and the factoring is part of the processing initialization, so I'm not especially worried about computational complexity.

EDIT: Just to be clear. I already have code find the prime factors. I'm looking for a way to combine those factors into as few composite factors as possible while keeping each factor less than N.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - it first looked like all factors were going to be less than N automatically, ie that the input *has no* factors not less than N.

Comment: Interesting question on the problem: assume that you want the factors of 33 not greater than 3. There is one that is prime (11) and bigger that 3. How do you want the code to deal with that?

Comment: In my problem space, I can just reject cases with a prime factor bigger than N.

Comment: So what would be the desired solution for 33 and 3? None, or just 3?

Comment: For the case of factoring 33 with a max factor of 3. The answer would be none. I need the product of all the factor to be the original number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve your problem by dividing it into two parts:

1. Factorize your number into primes using any of the [standard techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms). For a number of only a few million, trial division would be perfectly fine.
2. Take the logarithm of each factor, and [pack them into bins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) of size log *N*.

Now, bin packing is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) but in practice it is possible to find good approximate solutions using simple techniques: the first-fit algorithm packs no more than 11/9 times the optimal number of bins (plus one bin).

Here's an implementation in Python:

```py
from math import exp, log, sqrt
import operator

def factorize(n):
    """
    Factorize n by trial division and yield the prime factors.

    >>> list(factorize(24))
    [2, 2, 2, 3]
    >>> list(factorize(91))
    [7, 13]
    >>> list(factorize(999983))
    [999983]
    """
    for p in xrange(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        while n % p == 0:
            yield p
            n //= p
        if n == 1:
            return
    yield n

def product(s):
    """
    Return the product of the items in the sequence `s`.

    >>> from math import factorial
    >>> product(xrange(1,10)) == factorial(9)
    True
    """
    return reduce(operator.mul, s, 1)

def pack(objects, bin_size, cost=sum):
    """
    Pack the numbers in `objects` into a small number of bins of size
    `bin_size` using the first-fit decreasing algorithm. The optional
    argument `cost` is a function that computes the cost of a bin.

    >>> pack([2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8], 10)
    [[8, 2], [7, 3], [5, 4, 1]]
    >>> len(pack([6,6,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,3,7,7,5,5,8,8,4,4,5], 10))
    11
    """
    bins = []
    for o in sorted(objects, reverse=True):
        if o > bin_size:
            raise ValueError("Object {0} is bigger than bin {1}"
                             .format(o, bin_size))
        for b in bins:
            new_cost = cost([b[0], o])
            if new_cost <= bin_size:
                b[0] = new_cost
                b[1].append(o)
                break
        else:
            b = [o]
            bins.append([cost(b), b])
    return [b[1] for b in bins]

def small_factorization(n, m):
    """
    Factorize `n` into a small number of factors, subject to the
    constraint that each factor is less than or equal to `m`.

    >>> small_factorization(2400, 40)
    [25, 24, 4]
    >>> small_factorization(2400, 50)
    [50, 48]
    """
    return [product(b) for b in pack(factorize(n), m, cost=product)]
```

Comment: +1 I wanted to mention bin packing too. I just don't understand the reason for the logarithm?

Comment: bin packing adds stuff. But the OP is looking for factors so he wants to multiply. So Gareth is using the equality log(a*b)= log(a) + log(b)

Comment: This is exactly what a need. It seems like if I simply take the contents of each bin to be the product of factors in the bin, I can avoid having to explicitly deal with the logarithms.

Comment: Yes, you could implement any of the bin packing algorithms with multiplication rather than addition. In fact, you'd be better off doing so because you'd avoid problems arising from numerical inaccuracy. But the exposition is simpler if I explain it in terms of well-known problems.

Comment: One question: should small_factorization(2400, 40) return [25, 24, 4]? Since the remainder of the divisions between 2400 and both 40 and 32 return zero, aren't these factors more desirable? I understand that bin packing solution is heuristic and that is the root cause of this result, but is this the solution desired?

Comment: @rlinden: The OP doesn't say what he wants when there are multiple solutions with the same number of factors. Is [25, 24, 4] better or worse than [40, 30, 2] or [32, 15, 5]? In any case, there are other bin packing heuristics you might try.

Comment: @GarethRees: Your answer is exactly my question. Is there a difference between the three results? I believe that it depends on the OP intention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an established algorithm, but I would try the following

```
public static List<Integer> getFactors(int myNumber, int N) {
    int temp=N;
    int origNumber=myNumber;        
    List<Integer> results=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Factors of "+myNumber+" not greater than "+N);
    while (temp>1) {            
        if (myNumber % temp == 0) {
            results.add(temp);
            myNumber/=temp;                                
        } else {
            if (myNumber<temp) {
                temp= myNumber;                    
            } else {
                temp--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int div : results) {
        origNumber/=div;
    }
    if (origNumber>1) {
        results.clear();
    }        
    return(results);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't fully understand your pseudo-code. Did you mean `while (temp>1)`? And what is lowercase `n`? Also, OP wanted to get as few factors as possible. This seems like it's trying to factorize it completely (although it doesn't seem like it would work).

Comment: @Dilbert was right about the errors - hence I coded the algorithm in Java and tested. Now it works just fine.

Comment: This is actually not what OP wanted. You are only factoring the number, and it won't lead to the optimum solution since they are not prime (which is something OP said he already did). Also, it's very inefficient, because check every single `temp` value unnecessarily. Try to run it step by step for, say `myNumber = 200` and `N = 100`.

Comment: OP mentioned that he doesn't care about factors being prime. In his comment he even stated that he wanted 64 as a factor for 8192. I know the solution was not efficient - I wanted to offer a fisrt step for the solution in the limited time I have. Nevertheless, since you insist, I changed the algorithm to make the number of tests smaller. I tested in 10 different cases and it worked just fine.

Comment: +1. I think that for small numbers (a few millions) this is a faster and simpler solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then, if you can find a factor, you're done, because the second factor is just your number divided by the first factor. To make it fast, just use a sieve of primes. I guess the sieve is not very big if your largest number is in the range of millions.

Comment: Not if one of the factors is greater than N. Consider if N is 64 and I start with the integer 8192. I can factor that into 2048*2. That doesn't work because I need all the factors to be less than 64. For this case I would need the factors (64, 64, 2).

Comment: The question indicates that he is not necessarily interested in primes.

Comment: @John Oh, right, I've rather misread your question. Do you have any guarantees that each number has at least one small (prime) factor(s)?

Comment: I reject numbers with a prime factor greater than N.